# Typescript interface to define a generator

Tags: typescript, generator

I have some code that look like this:

```
const saga =  function* (action) {
        yield put({
            type: actions.SUCCESS,
            payload: action.payload
        });
    };


const sagaWatcher =  createDefaultSagaWatcher(actions, saga);
```

That I am converting to TypeScript.

I need to create an interface for the generator function, so I can add type checking on the `createDefaultSagaWatcher` function. How do I do this?

I've tried doing something like this:

```
interface ReduxSaga {
    (action: ReduxAction)* : any; 
}
```

but that syntax is incorrect.

Comment: In the latest Typescript Language Specification there is a TODO to document how it works. It also links to a closed issue which has partially been implemented. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#6.7

Comment: @JonasBerlin Oh huh, fantastic resource, thanks.

Comment: The [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) talks about "Strongly typed iterators and generators" to be included in the 3.6 release in July 2019. Linked issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2983

Answer (score 0):

Much like the `async` modifier, the `*` is an implementation detail. The important part for the caller of the function is that the function returns something that can be iterated, how that iteration is implemented should not matter to the caller. Since you want the iteration
to return anything you can use `IterableIterator<any>`

```
interface ReduxSaga {
    (action: ReduxAction): IterableIterator<any>; 
}
```